# When throwing an Error, how to read the error data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to read/handle error case in React JS project, but cant resolve/read error data in catch.
Can't get the "code" field out of the error data.

[image]

```
try {
  dispatch({ type: types.READ_DATA })
  const response = await new DataApi().readData(action.payload);
  processResponse(response, [200], "Read data failed", dispatch);
  dispatch({
    type: types.DATA_READ,
    data: response.data
  })
} catch (error) {
  console.error("MIDDLEWARE. CATCH ERROR: ", error);
  dispatch({ type: types.DATA_FAILED, data: { Code: error.code } })
}

const processResponse = (response, okCodes, errorMessage, dispatch) => {
if (response && response.status) {
  if (okCodes.indexOf(response.status) < 0) {
    errorHandler(response.status, dispatch);
    throw Error({ code: response.status, message: errorMessage });
  }
} else {
  throw Error("Error reading response status");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.error(JSON.stringify(error))` to get the object in a string format.

Comment: Now, when I trying to read the error code, I get empty string {}
    catch (error) {
      var errordata =  JSON.stringify(error);
      console.error("MIDDLEWARE. CATCH ERROR: ", errordata);
      dispatch({ type: types.NEXTNURSINGTIMES_FAILED, data: { Code: errordata.code } })
    }

Comment: Use `error.code`  in the dispatch call. Use `errordata` in console.error only.

Comment: The JSON.stringify(error) still prints empty string {} and that error.code is undefined, so dispatch wont work. Can you help me bit more?

Comment: `{}` means the object is empty so `error` is an empty object. You need to check the code for the functions in `try` block where they're throwing an error.

Comment: I'll get the HTTP Status code right and pass it to the processResponse function, where I throw the Error
     throw Error({ code: response.status, message: errorMessage });

The message parameter is just in case, if later is need more info.

And after this in catch(erro) I try to read this http status code and pass it on (dispatch),
so calling component can handle the situation.

Comment: `Error()` expects a string, not an object. so you need to do `throw Error(errorMessage)` then in the `catch` block you can read it via `console.error(error.message)` without `stringify`.